# What does `post` in `Got a tablet for Christmas` Hat mean?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

The description of [Got a tablet for Christmas](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/got-a-tablet-for-christmas) hat is given when you post from the Stack Exchange app on 25<sup>th</sup> December 2014.

My question is:

- The hat name has Tablet, so do we have to use the Stack Exchange app on tablets to get this hat ? Or any Android / iOS device will work ?
- What all does `post` cover here ? Will either posting an answer or posting a question work ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No you don't need a tablet. You simply need to use either the Android or iOS app to post.
2. The term post is a general term that encompasses *both* questions and answers. So you would need to ask or answer a question on that day. Commenting does not count.

Also don't forget that the post will need to have a score higher than zero.

Comment: inb4 MSE posts on Christmas

Comment: inb4 *Does it have to be a **new** Android or iOS device?*

Comment: @Martijn New hat description: "submit proof of receipt of new mobile device via that new mobile device on Christmas Day"

Comment: @animuson Where would a normal user have found this rule on what a "post" is defined as without searching Meta for the answer?  If a user isn't a Meta regular, it could be perceived that a comment would count as a "post".

Answer (score 3):

The hat description doesn't say that you have to use a tablet. It just says that you have to post from one of the apps, so any device will work.

"post" here means: post a question or an answer.